# Bash parameter expansion to replace exact matches only

Tags: bash

Is it possible to use bash parameter expansion to replace $VAR with `''` if and only if it matches some `'value'` *exactly*?

There is the syntax `${VAR#value}` which removes `value` the beginning of `$VAR` and similarly `${VAR%value}` which removes it from the end. This does replace `value` with `''`, but if `$VAR` is something like `value1` or `1value`, it could replace it with `1`, but in those cases it should remain unchanged.

I know I can do this with an `if` statement, but I am trying to add something to my `PS1` that is not shown if it equals some value, which is why I need to use parameter expansion, or some other kind of inline syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably go for parameter expansion of the `$()` kind:

```
PS1='$( [[ "${VAR}" == value ]] || printf %s "${VAR}" )$ '
```

Beware it removes trailing newline characters from the value of `$VAR`.

Answer (score 2):

If switching to `zsh` is an option, you can use `${VAR:#value}` or the ksh93 style `${VAR/#%value}`.

`${var/pattern[/replacement]}` comes from ksh93 and has also been copied by bash. ksh93 also lets you anchor the search at the start with `${var/#pattern}` or end with `${var/%pattern}` but doesn't let you combine both. bash doesn't either but  zsh does with `${var/#%pattern}`.

See [`info zsh 'Parameter Expansion'`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) for details.

With the `extendedglob` option on, you also get `(#s)` and `(#e)` glob pattern operators ([Globbing Flags](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Globbing-Flags)) that match respectively at the `s`tart (like regex `^`) and `e`nd (like regex `$`) of the subject, so after `set -o extendedlob`, you can also use `${VAR/(#s)value(#e)}` or `${VAR#value(#e)}` or `${VAR%(#s)value}`.

---

If it's about prompt expansion, you'd be better of preparing the text you want to include in a `precmd` hook (or `$PROMPT_COMMAND` in bash), something like:

```
prompt-from-VAR() {
  case $VAR in
    (value) psvar[1]=;;
    (something-else) psvar[1]=OTHER;;
    (*) psvar[1]=$VAR;;
  esac
}
autoload add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd prompt-from-VAR
PS1='%1v$ '
```

(here using `$psvar` and `%v` instead of the more dangerous `prompsubst` option).

In bash that has no equivalent to `psvar` or `precmd` hooks:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND"'
  case $var in
    (value) promt_VAR=;;
    (something-else) prompt_VAR=OTHER;;
    (*) prompt_VAR=$VAR;;
  esac'
PS1='${prompt_VAR}$ '
```